# How do I run a Rails application permanently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'm a Ruby on Rails newb and I'm running my application on an EC2 instance w/ ubuntu. Here's a [link](http://intelligentinvestor.ca:3001). Everything seems to be running fine when I enter the command:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

However, this doesn't run permanently. It works for a little while, but even if I leave it running the Rails application eventually just stops.

Am I missing something basic here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run it as a daemon
rails s -d -p 3000

Answer (score 0):

It's worth bearing in mind that this will load your Rails app using WebBrick which is not great performance-wise. It might be worth adding Unicorn to your Gemfile at the very least or even setting up an nginx/passenger stack for even better performance.